Does Buddhist Literature mention any of the former Buddhas taking birth in Kikata-Pradesa (Modern day Gaya)?
There’s a new theory, which I saw many Vaiṣṇava groups propagating, of the 2 buddhas: Viṣṇu incarnate Ādi Buddha and the other being Śākyamuni of Buddhism, as two seperate personalities, based on the  differences in Buddha stories from the Vaiṣṇava texts and Śākyamuni’s story in Buddhist texts. I have briefly talked about it in the addendum to this answer as well.
They cite the details mentioned in the Bhāgvata Puruāṇa to claim that Viṣṇu-incarnate Buddha was a different person born centuries before the Gautama Buddha, gave teachings of compassion and leaving animal slaughter, then centuries later Siddhārtha came to bodh gaya, gained enlightenment there as the place had increased spiritual potency.
To Quote from this article-

tatah kalau sampravritte sammohaya sura-dvisham
buddho namnanjana-sutah kikateshu bhavishyati
(srimad-bhagavatam 1.3.24)

“Thereafter, in the twenty-first manvantara at the beginning of
Kali-yuga, the Lord will appear as Lord Buddha, the son of Anjana,
in Kikata Pradesa (the province of present day Gaya-Bihar), just for the purpose
of deluding those who are envious of the faithful demigods.”

As anyone can see that the stated birth place does not coincide with the Birth place of the historical Gautama Buddha. To supposedly reconcile this apparent contradiction, they cite the theory that the Vishnu incarnate buddha was a different person from Gautama buddha for which they cite the following proof-

Thus, Sugata Buddha and Sunyavadi (Sakyasimha) Buddha are not the same
person. Further evidence is found in Mr. H.T.Colebrooke’s Amarakosha,
published at Ramapura in 1807. It is written in Chapter 21, Page 178
of Lalitavistara-grantha that Gautama Buddha performed penances at the
same place as the previous Buddha (Vishnu-avatara Buddha). Maybe it is
for this reason that in later ages he and Lord Buddha are considered
as being one:
esha dharanimunde purvabuddhasanasthah
samartha dhanurgrihitva sunya nairatmavanaih
klesaripum nihatva drishtijalanca bhitva-siva
virajamsokam prapsyate bodhimagryam


What's more to support this notion, they cite even a Buddhist text named  Lankavatara-sutra -

There is an authentic Buddhist book, Lankavatara-sutra[8], in which
Ravana, the king of Lanka, prays to Jina’s son, the ancient Lord
Buddha, and to all the Buddhas and Buddhas’ sons who would appear in
the future, via this eulogy (stava):
atha ravano lankadhipatih gathagiten anugayati sma
lankavatarasutram vaih purvabuddhanuvarnitam
smarami purvakaih buddhairjinaputra-puraskritaih
putrametannigadyate bhagavanapi bhashatam
bhavishyantyanapate kale buddha buddhasutasca ye

Therefore, this source leaves no doubt that the ancient avatara-Buddha
and the modern Gautama Buddha are not the same person.

Questions -

As I saw from the Answers of this question, there is indeed a conception of many Buddhas in the Buddhist literature. Does any of the buddhist literature mention any account one of the former buddhas taking birth in Present Day Gaya (Kikata-pradesa)?

Since it is Gaya alone where Gautama Buddha attained enlightenment, Does Gautama buddha mention any of the former buddhas taking birth in that place in any of his discourses? As the Buddha was omniscient, he would have certainly known about the former buddhas and if any of them had actually taken birth in kikata pradesa (aka present day Gaya).




Vipassī’s father was King Bandhumā, his birth mother was Queen
Bandhumatī, and their capital city was named Bandhumatī.
Sikhī’s father was King Aruṇa, his birth mother was Queen Pabhāvatī,
and their capital city was named Aruṇavatī.
Vessabhū’s father was King Suppatita, his birth mother was Queen
Vassavatī, and their capital city was named Anoma.
Kakusandha’s father was the brahmin Aggidatta, and his birth mother
was the brahmin lady Visākhā. At that time the king was Khema, whose
capital city was named Khemavatī.
Koṇāgamana’s father was the brahmin Yaññadatta, and his birth mother
was the brahmin lady Uttarā. At that time the king was Sobha, whose
capital city was named Sobhavatī.
Kassapa’s father was the brahmin Brahmadatta, and his birth mother was
the brahmin lady Dhanavatī. At that time the king was Kikī, whose
capital city was named Varanasi.
In this life, my father was King Suddhodana, my birth mother was Queen
Māyā, and our capital city was Kapilavatthu.”
DN 14


So In other words, none of the buddhas were born in Gaya?

Varanasi is near Gaya. Also, Gotama's family did their shopping in  Varanasi https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.038.than.html

Still doesn't tally with the  Buddha of the Bhagavata because their mother is named Anjana and not Dhanavati. Were there any former buddhas whose mother was named Anjana?
